# visual studio 092 on ubuntu c++ code run issue -- error message "launch: property 'program' is missing or empty"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ubuntu

After running c++ code in visual studio on ubuntu i have got next error:

```
error message "launch: property 'program' is missing or empty"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your startup project must be a C++ project. Right-click it, then click Properties => Debugging => Working Directory setting. Default is $(ProjectDir) . It sounds like yours is empty.

Comment: i nothing understand, i trying to click properties but here only 3 tabs basic permissions and open with, and nothing about debugging, in visual studio i also trying to see something about this, but only changed plain text on c++ in downbar